# How do I push changes in a submodule to GitHub?

Tags: git, github

My repo `R` contains a submodule `S`. I do not own `S` and I cannot push to `S` on GitHub. However, I made some local changes in `S` (and committed them) which I need for my repo `R`.  Now, when I `git push origin main` in `R`, GitHub creates a symlink that leads to a 404 because the changes I made to `S` are not on the original repo (`S`'s remote origin). How can I fix this?

Comment: You will need to get someone to update S on GitHub (if you can) or fork S (if you can't). If you fork S to your own clone, you can push *there* and then modify your R to refer to your fork instead of the original S.

Comment: That's what I suspected, thanks for the clarification. I ended up forking S.